# Unused functions

Tags: php, wordpress

This is a general Wordpress question. When I download a theme I want to customize, it comes packed with tons of features (different page layouts, page builders, etc.)

I usually only use a fraction of what is included and have o need for the rest. But I upload the entire theme. So all the pages, functions, etc get put in my 'head' tag.

I've seen other people who use these themes and only use a small part of their functions, when I look at their head tags only essential pages/.php's/etc are brought in, not everything even though it says .../themes/themeName/... (doesn't appear to be a child).

EDIT  - Clarification

I have made child themes, and went through numerous function files and 'unenquened' and 'unregistered' pages and functions, etc. When dealing with a huge theme, its tedious. I was wondering if there is a plugin or technique used that makes it easier. Similar to 'select all unused' in adobe programs

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I guess I am looking for the ways people are 'un-using' functions that come with themes. Most themes have tons of functionality and  just change the original theme using the wp-admin. I don't want all the unused functionality in my head tag when uploaded

Comment: So, are you looking for a way to achieve this? Or are you asking if that is legal / possible / a good idea?

Comment: I have made child themes, and went through numerous function files and 'unenquened' and 'unregistered' pages and functions, etc. When dealing with a huge theme, its tedious. I was wondering if there is a plugin or technique used that makes it easier. Similar to 'select all unused' in adobe programs

Comment: Okay. It is clearer now. Maybe you should edit your question and add this piece of information.

Comment: I will do that, if it makes it clearer

Comment: What exactly do you want to remove and under what conditions? It's the extra menu entries in the admin? If so by hooking `admin_menu` action and using `remove_menu_page` you can remove some menu entries.

Answer (score 1):

Do not remove anything, or you will probably break something. Build a child theme: it's a theme that inherits all the functions of the theme you bought. To create a child theme, just create a new folder in `wp-content/themes`, create a file named `style.css` in it with this comment at the top:

```
/*
Theme Name: My Child theme
Theme URI: 
Description: My awesome child theme
Author: You
Author URI: 
Template: parent_theme_name
Version: 1.0.0
*/
```

Just replace `parent_theme_name` by the name of the theme you bought. Activate that child theme, then start working on that one - you can override all the templates, build your own `functions.php` etc.

Note that working with a child theme is a good practice: then you don't touch at all the theme you bought, and then you're able to upgrade it if there is any security issue about it (which happens honestly a lot).

Read more : https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: will that bring all the functions/php of the original theme in the head tags when someone goes to the site?

Comment: It will use the `header.php` from the parent theme unless you override it.

Comment: Even if you add your own functions.php file, you will almost positively inherit the parent theme's functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to make extensive changes to a theme, if a child theme doesn't accomplish everything you're looking to do, instead of trying to figure out what to suppress from the theme, it's probably time to start learning how to make your own theme.

Depending on the theme, if it's an open source theme, and if the developer doesn't mind, you can use that theme as a starting point to get to what you are trying to accomplish. Or you can use that theme to play around and start learning, and then go make your own theme. This way you'll know exactly what gets loaded and control everything you need to.

Start here and see where it takes you: https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Comment: My biggest concern is when the theme updates. A lot of times I want to make extensive changes, and it would be much easier to just copy the parent theme and delete fuctions/pages instead of surprising them. I just am not sure how to dibble its ability to be updated

Comment: You shouldn't make changes to a theme that's not yours. Any change you make will overwrite anything you do. That's why you can create your own theme by using the one you want as a starting point.